# Load two templates in a root route in angularjs using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Please can someone help me with this problem.

```
    .state('home',{
        url:'home',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })

    .state('home.profile',{
        url:'/profile',
        controller: 'proCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'profile.html'
    })

    .state('home.category',{
        url:'/category',
        controller: 'cateCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'category.html'
    })
```

My index page is like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul class="nav panel-group rm-border">
                <li>
                    <a click-toggle ui-sref-active="active" class="row" ui-sref="home.profile">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a click-toggle ui-sref-active="active" class="row" ui-sref="home.category">category</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><br clear="all">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 no-padding">
        <div class="row panel-heading rm-border no-margin">
            <h4 class="panel-title"> {{title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-margin" ui-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please i want a situation whereby i can load both index.html and also load another template when one click on my root "/home" route.

Comment: Try adding an otherwise statement to go to /home

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have your `Home` and `category` pages have this type of layout

HOME

```
<div> 
show some cool things
</div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

CATEGORY

```
<div>
cool category things
</div>
```

Following [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#nested-states--views) guide will get you there. But in essence the view that needs to have another view 'nested' will need to have a `div` or another `html element` have the `ui-view` attribute on it

quick link to their [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, i just did a redirect. It solves my problem.